# RoutePrefix does not work Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, attributes

RoutePrefix does not work for me.

Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("example-name")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
}
```

Rout Config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
       routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Index Page

```
 @Html.ActionLink("click me", "index","example-name");
```

i have complete all the basic steps, however i am getting 404 not

> The resource cannot be found.

version of `System.Web.Mvc.dll` is 5.2.3.0

Comment: please se my reply : i found issue with your code ...you need to specify Route attribute for the action if you specify RoutePrefix attribute for the control.....you havent applied [Route] on your method

Comment: can you please try step by step i suggested and once you do change you need to paste this url : http://localhost:8080/hometest/Index

Answer (score 17):

I think I found solution , you have to do following changes

1.most important thing you miss is : **you need to specify Route attribute for the action if you specify RoutePrefix attribute for the control.**

```
 [RoutePrefix("hometest")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

          [Route("About")]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
}
```

2.your html view like this

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("hometext", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "hometest")</li>
```

3.move  `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` before `MapRoute` as below.

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks For helping me however the solution does not work for me. Same steps i follow.

Comment: Issue is i am not able to find the controller, 404 error is for controller if the view is not found asp.net show different exception view not found.

Comment: after doing change just do like this : http://localhost:8080/hometest/Index....here localhost port number get replace by your machine details ...if you are starting from visual studio just add /hometest/Index

Comment: You don't have to specify the Route-Attribute on every Action.  You could define `[Route("{action}")]` as an Attribute on the Controller instead.  Also, wouldn't your `controllerName` be `"Home"` and not `"hometest"` in your 2nd step above?

Answer (score 8):

Put

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

before any other routes configuration methods

Comment: he for got [Route]...that is the issue.